# std::filebuf open file, create if it doesn't exist

Tags: c++, fstream, filebuf

I want to open a file for read and write with `std::filebuf`, but create the file if it doesn't exist yet. If it already exists, do nothing. I want to freely write into the file, without any "always jump to end before each write" behavior. What open mode should be used?

According to the [table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) , there appears to be no combination of flags to do that.

What's the best option to ensure this effect?

Comment: Is it a requirement to open the file only once?  If not, this sequence may serve: Open for append, close, open for read+write?

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks, that would work. You may answer. But I find it surprising that such a simple task requires that workaround. It would appear to me that's the most frequent usecase I'm facing.